# Creating Pivot Table taking time at average vales

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I need help with VBA code.

I have created a macro to create pivot table automatically. But taking 15 to 20 minutes of time to complete the macro.

Especially at the point of below code taking half of the time. Review Code below

```
    With .PivotFields("NTS USD ACT Previous Year")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlAverage
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##;($#,##);-"
        .Caption = "FG NTS PY-Average"
    End With
```

Requirements:

1. Pivot Table should be in Tabular Format.
2. Grand Total should be there and when I filter for single "JNJ RM Code" Grand should change.
3. Row Sub totals should be turned off.
4. Repeat all data labels.
5. Adjust Pivot table Column width

Seeking Advice: Can I have 200,000 data on excel sheet and to use pivot.

Please do suggest how much data maximum excel can hold with better performance.

Please review the entire module for your reference.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPT As Worksheet

Sub Create_Pivot_Table()
Dim LR As Long, LC As Byte
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim st As String
st = Now()

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Data")

Call Delete_PT_Sheet

With wsData
LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))

Set wsPT = wb.Worksheets.Add

wsPT.Name = "Pivot_Data"

Set PTCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, DataRange)
Set pt = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(wsPT.Range("A2"), "Data")

    With pt
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .VisualTotals = False
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = True
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = True
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .DisplayImmediateItems = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
        .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels

        '// Filter(s)
        With .PivotFields("Region")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
            .Subtotals(1) = True
            .Subtotals(1) = False
        End With
        
        '// Row Section (Layer 1)
        With .PivotFields("JNJ RM Code")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            .LayoutBlankLine = False
            
            .Subtotals(1) = True
            .Subtotals(1) = False
            .LayoutForm = xlTabular 'xlOutline
            .LayoutCompactRow = True
        End With
        
        '// Row Section (Layer 2)
        With .PivotFields("Component Description")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
            .LayoutBlankLine = False
            .Subtotals(1) = True
            .Subtotals(1) = False
        End With
                
        '// Row Section (Layer 3)
        With .PivotFields("FG Material Code")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
            .LayoutBlankLine = False
            .Subtotals(1) = True
            .Subtotals(1) = False
        End With
         
        '// Row Section (Layer 4)
        With .PivotFields("FG Material Description")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 4
            .LayoutBlankLine = False
            .Subtotals(1) = True
            .Subtotals(1) = False
        End With
        
        '// Values Section Layer 2)
        With .PivotFields("NTS USD ACT Previous Year")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 1
            .Function = xlAverage
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##;($#,##);-"
            .Caption = "FG NTS PY-Average"
        End With
    
    End With 'PT

End With 'wsData


'//Releasing Object Memories
Set PTCache = Nothing
Set wsPT = Nothing
Set DataRange = Nothing
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Save

'MsgBox ("Completed")

End Sub
```

Comment: Try disabling screen updates to increase speed.

`Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Place main VBA code here
Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: @XLmatters Yes, I turned events off.